# Failed to execute PCL code in callback (ROS)

Tags: c++, ros, point-cloud-library

I have a C++ code in ROS format. The following is the callback function:

```
void cloud_cb(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>& input){
    ROS_INFO("callback");
    pcl::PCLPointCloud2 pcl_pc2;
    pcl_conversions::toPCL(*input,pcl_pc2);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(pcl_pc2,*cloud);
    if(cloud->size() > 300) {
        ROS_INFO("if loop");
        pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr kdtree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);
        ROS_INFO("1");
        pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> normal_estimation; 
        ROS_INFO("2");
        normal_estimation.setInputCloud (cloud);
        ROS_INFO("3");
        normal_estimation.setSearchMethod (kdtree);
        ROS_INFO("4");
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normals (new pcl::PointCloud< pcl::Normal>);
        ROS_INFO("5");
        normal_estimation.setRadiusSearch (0.03);
        ROS_INFO("6");
        normal_estimation.compute (*normals);
        ROS_INFO("7");
        PFHShapeReco<pcl::PointXYZ> pfh;
        ROS_INFO("8");
        pfh.ComputePFH(0.5, cloud, normals);
        ROS_INFO("9");
        std_msgs::Float32MultiArray arr;
        for(int i = 0; i < 625; i++){
            float f = pfh.GetObjectModel()[i];
            arr.data.push_back(f);
        }
        hist.publish (arr);
    }
}
```

Note that I have added the various ROS_INFO messages as checkpoints. The problem here is the lag between checkpoint 6 and 7. The following statement takes a lot of time to implement,

> normal_estimation.compute (*normals);

The code is exactly the same as in [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation.php#normal-estimation).

Could this be a problem with the code? Are these statements incapable to be implemented in a callback function.?

Comment: So what is the problem? That it takes time to compute the normals?

Comment: Yes that's it. I am implementing a real-time system, so need continuous data computation without lag.

Comment: Then you should rewrite the question and mention that as the problem. Right now what is written points to some undefined failure. Also note that computing normals IS an expensive process.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I edited the question!

Comment: Is there a way to implement this code for a real time system without experiencing the lag? Could it just be rectified by implementing on a better system?